# BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted on CIContext with iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, core-image

I have got some problems on my app right now. I would like to create a CIContext with :

```
CIContext *myContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
```

But when starting the app, this line return the following message in console : "BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted"

This message come when I launch the app on iOS 8 (simulator or device), but not with an iOS 7 simulator (I don't have a device to try). I tried many things to solve this like try it in another projet, on another Mac, call this method on another file... I think it come from iOS 8.

It don't look to change my image processing (what I use the context to), but if there is a warning, there is a problem to solve.

Thank for your help :)

Comment: there is no message on a physical 7.1.2 device either, not just on simulator. Looks like we got ourselves a bug for bugreporter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm having the same problem:  I get the "BSXPCMessage..." message in iOS 8, but not iOS 7.

I traced it to where I create the CIContext:

```
self.ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @(NO)}];
```

If you set kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer to YES, the error goes away. Maybe iOS 8 requires you to enable CPU rendering?

Comment: Thank you @anna-dickinson! Here's the code in Swift: `let context = CIContext(options:[kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : true])`

Comment: Isn't the software renderer slower?

Comment: I haven't done any measurements, but I assume it depends on context -- different amounts of overhead in each case. I also think, "use software renderer" could mean "ALLOW use of software renderer" -- not "ONLY use software renderer." So, maybe it uses the GPU when it can. The docs are unclear on that point.

Comment: It's a lot slower. I'm having this error and have tried the solution but it's gone from taking 2 seconds to generate to almost 10…

Answer (score 0):

connection interrupted means that the XPC connection in question was interrupted (either by the remote of the connection quitting or possibly crashing).  Assuming the other side is an XPC Service, App Extension, or Launch Daemon, this is usually not fatal and the connection will be restored by launchd restarting the service.

Are there any crash logs saved to ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports around this time?

Do you see anything interesting in the device's syslog at this time?

Is there anything wrong happening other than the unexpected message?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, there is no log in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports nor in the device's logs, and nothing wrong happened other than this message.